# Script skipping a column

Tags: bash, shell-script

my script is supposed to go through each column from 1 to 13 but it ignores -f13. I changed it to -f14 just to see what it does and it printed out what I needed from -f13. Why does this happen?

```
           PMRNUM=`echo $ln | cut -d "," -f2                     
           PMRMGR=`echo $ln | cut -d "," -f3`             
           MAJORINCIDENT=`echo $ln | cut -d "," -f1`                                             
           ASSIGNMENTGROUP=`echo $ln | cut -d "," -f4`
           DUEDATE=`echo $ln | cut -d "," -f5`
           PRIMARYAPP=`echo $ln | cut -d "," -f6`
           IMPACTEDREGIONS=`echo $ln | cut -d "," -f7`
           IMPACTEDCOUNTRIES=`echo $ln | cut -d "," -f8`
           INTERNALEXTERNAL=`echo $ln | cut -d "," -f9`
           BUSINESSIMPACTDESCRIPTION=`echo $ln | cut -d "," -f10`
           PRBSTATE=`echo $ln | cut -d "," -f11`
           RCL1=`echo $ln | cut -d "," -f12`
           RCL2=`echo $ln | cut -d "," -f14`
```

Comment: Guessing you're talking of a shell script, use  `read TMP PMRNUM PMRMGR  MAJORINCIDENT ASSIGNMENTGROUP . . .  <<< $ln` to eliminate your problem and improve the script.

Comment: As soon as you start calling `cut`, `awk`, `grep` or `sed` _in a loop_, you most stop yourself and ask whether there's a better way of doing it. Your code is madness.

Comment: i cant think of any other way since i got no training and was handed this project a few days ago. im sorry it isnt up to your standards. im trying to get something to work with what i know. if youre going to insult my code rather than try to help then id much rather you not comment at all.

Comment: It would be easy to come with suggestions for improvement that would make your life easier, but it requires that you show a representabre sample of the data. Without seeing a sample of the data, nobody can suggest how to parse it. I'm definitely *not* intending to insult you, but the code is simply not suitable for running in a production environment for several reasons. I'm truly sorry if my previous comment used the wrong words for saying so.

Comment: To reiterate and emphasize what @Kusalananda wrote, this code is indeed madness.  There is no need to take that as an insult.   I'm sure everyone wrote code exactly like that when learning because samples like this are abundant.  The best way (perhaps only way) to learn anything is to make mistakes, but those mistakes are only instructional if you recognize that they are mistakes.  This code is a mistake!  See RudiC 's for a much better approach.

Comment: Show some input data.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you have an extra delimiter in your data before column 13.

Comment: i've added the code in - could you please check?

Comment: @infiniteoscillation I can say nothing more until you show the actual data.